# How do I add Images to Divs using JavaScript when the src contains variables?

Tags: javascript, html, image, var

I have a  function that is supposed to add 10 random images to a div by generating a number at random. This is the function:

```
function Images()
        {
            clore();
            var total = 133;
            var gif = 3;
            var name = "FileName";
            var i = 0;
            while (i < 10)
            {
                var num = random.nextInt(total - 1 + 1) + 1;
                if(num > (total - gif))
                {
                    var type = ".gif";
                }else{
                    var type = ".jpg";
                }
                var elem = document.createElement("img");
                elem.src = 'images/' + name + '/' + num + type;
                document.getElementById("DIV").appendChild(elem);
                i++;
            }
        }
```

clore() - Clears the innerhtml of the div

var total - the total number of ALL images in the folder

var gif - the total number of .gif images in the folder

var name - the name of the folder the images are in

The images are named 1 to 133, all of them are .jpg except the last three which are .gif.

So it goes: 1.jpg.....130.jpg then 131.gif.....133.gif .

I know the function is running because the clore function clears the div but nothing happens after that.

I also know I am not using any reserved terms as I have changed all of the names repeatedly?

Comment: JavaScript has no `random.nextInt` method. Perhaps you're confusing it with Java?

Comment: I have used Math.floor(Math.random() * (total +1)); and variations upon that to no avail

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qbehvaaL/

Comment: If this does not solve your issue then it's something else besides this function that's breaking the program. You should check the developer console for errors and also step through your functions that you've written to make sure they're receiving the expected input and generating the expected output. Another recommendation is to change your container's ID to something other than "DIV", that's not descriptive or clarifying, and most developers would be led to believe you mistook the ID for a tag name.

Comment: I have made sure all id's are correct and renamed them. I created a new html document with only the function from above, a button to call it and the div the images are meant to be placed in, still noting happens.

Comment: You didn't mention checking the developer console for errors. "Nothing happens" could mean several things. Either the function never gets called or it throws an error, and we won't know until you tell us.

Comment: Please refer to creating a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the line where you have:

```
var num = random.nextInt(total - 1 + 1) + 1;
```

Instead it should be:

```
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * total) + 1;
```